# [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x108db9208`

Tags: ios, nscalendar

I have a method which adds years to a date. While it works on my iPhone 5c iOS8, it fails in the simulator 5s iOS7.1

Here the method:

```
+ (NSDate *)addYears:(int)years toDate:(NSDate *)datum{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components= [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setYear:years];
    return [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:datum options:0];
}
```

The exception is thrown in `NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];`

`+[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x108db9208`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try on a real iOS7 device ? or on an iOS8 sim ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a method of `EKEventStore`, not `NSCalendar`.

You want:

```
NSCalendar *gregarian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

Comment: I got `+ (id)calendarWithIdentifier:(NSString *)calendarIdentifierConstant NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, __NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_7_0);` in `NSCalendar.h` on iOS7 SDK

Comment: The NSCalendar.h in iOS 8 shows that `calendarWithIdentifier:` was added in iOS 8. Since it's not in iOS 7, use the code in my answer for both versions.

Comment: In fact, this seems trickier than that, because I can see it on iOS7 (with Xcode 5) and it says `__NSCALENDAR_COND_IOS_7_0`, but in the iOS8 SDK, I can see `8_0` requirements. Seems awkward !

Comment: You aren't using the iOS 7 SDK in Xcode 5. You are using the iOS 8 SDK in Xcode 6. The simple solution is to use the method available now in both versions of iOS, as posted in my answer.

Comment: You are right about where the method belongs. Don't know why Xcode compiled without complaining???

Comment: It's not complaining because you are building with a Base SDK of iOS 8 and it is a valid method in iOS 8.

Comment: @rmaddy Why are you saying that I'm not using Xcode 5 ... ?
I'm just saying that using Xcode 5 + SDK 7, I see this method available on iOS7 (seeing 7.1 -> NSCalendar.h). And that's what I find strange. That's all ...

Comment: I misread the question about iOS 8. Your question doesn't actually say what version of Xcode or what your Base SDK is. Is assumed Xcode 6 and a Base SDK of iOS 8 from your statement about running on an iOS 8 device. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You must have ignored some severe warnings from your compiler. That class method just doesn't exist.

You may look into the header file to find an init method that does exactly what you want.

Comment: There's no warning because the method was added in iOS 8 but it's not in iOS 7, hence the crash.